# why my http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/service/api/people returning blank people json object?

Tags: json, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have a list of user in my alfresco share, which i can access by login to alfresco, but while accessing the list of people through IP given below

127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/service/API/people

I am getting the output

`{
    "people" : [
    ]
}`

what should i do to resolve it? 
I have tried the re-installation of alfresco, but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are authenticated?

I would suggest you either get an alf_ticket and append it to your url or simply login to share and use the proxy entpoint : `127.0.0.1:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/API/people`

Comment: yes i've complete access to it. I have also tried with alt_ticket while accessing groups. But not getting any groups also where as in alfresco groups and user are there.